# Running curl to upload file to s3 fails in detached run command on Heroku

Tags: curl, heroku, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload a Heroku Postgres backup file into s3 via the following curl command:

```
heroku run:detached --app APPNAME 'curl --tlsv1 "https://PATH/TO/BACKUP/FROM/HEROKU/PGBACKUP/WITH/SIGNATURE/FILE.pgbackup" | aws s3 cp - s3://BUCKETNAME/POSTGRES_BACKUP_HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_RED_URL_2015-09-11.pgbackup'
```

Running the curl local as well as regular run command is working fine. Detaching it (`run:detached`), fails after transferring a few GB with the following error in the log:

```
2015-09-11T09:41:29.003185+00:00 app[run.8021]: upload failed: ./- to s3://BUCKETNAME/POSTGRES_BACKUP_HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_RED_URL_2015-09-11.pgbackup
2015-09-11T09:46:41.385893+00:00 app[run.8021]: (104, 'ECONNRESET')
```

What is the difference and how can I can get it going?